# Bellman's equation solution for grid problem

Tags: reinforcement-learning

While solving an RL problem from the University of Alberta online course, I made a modification to check if my understanding is written. I came upon the answer which I suspect is not correct.

I will state the problem first. The image is below.

The grid has 4 subgrids and each subgrid is an state $S$, $S$ = $\{A,B,C,D\}$.
The agent can take any of the following action from action set $A$ with equal probability (i.e. $\pi(a|s) = 4$). $A$ = $\{L,R,U D\}$. I will appreciate if someone can find tell me if it is wrong or correct?

The agent will earn a point when it moves to State $B$, even if it is a rebound from within $B$. If the agent leave $B$, then it will be penalized with $-1$ reward. Every other action has a reward of $0$.

I suspect that the value function for $\{A,B,C,D\}$ should have been $\{V_A, V_B, V_D, V_D\} = \{3.52,3.92,2.0,3.52 \}$. Instead I am getting teh value as shown in the figure below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is wrong. I solved it and found the answer to be following

$\{V_A = 3.4375, V_B = 3.77, V_C = 1.85, V_D = 3.4375\}$

Observe that the value at state $C$ is the least, where as the value at state $A$ and $B$ should be same given the equal probabilities for each action.